# My jump never stops

Tags: c++, sfml, jumping

I'm making a short jump test in SFML. However I have a problem: whenever the jump button is pressed the character will jump but will not fall down, he will keep going higher. However, in the beginning of the test, I made the sprite above the ground to see if the gravity function worked, but this still happens. [Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1stqaFJ51Q9RlfxTwqPLgbPvAPCJKIFT2/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code:

```c
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

float VelocityX = 0, VelocityY = 0;
float x = 0, y = 0;
int gravity = 2;
float dt;

void movement() {
    if (y < 444) {
        VelocityY += gravity * dt;
    }
    else if (y > 444) {
        y = 444;
    }
    x += VelocityX;
    y += VelocityY;
}

int main() {
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "jump test");
    RectangleShape rect(Vector2f(20, 20));
    const int moveSpeed = 500, jumpForce = 10;
    
    Clock deltaTime;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        dt = deltaTime.restart().asSeconds();
        Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) {
            VelocityX = moveSpeed * dt;
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) {
            VelocityX = -moveSpeed * dt;
        }
        else {
            VelocityX = 0;
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space)) {
            VelocityY -= jumpForce;
        }
        
        movement();
        rect.setPosition(x, y);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(rect);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***EDIT:*** The previous problem is fixed but there is still an issue, the character's jumping height is inconsistent, the height of the jump will randomly change. Here is the new code:

```c
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

float VelocityX = 0, VelocityY = 0;
float x = 0, y = 0;
int gravity = 5;
float dt;
bool isOnFloor;

void movement() {
    if (y < 444) {
        VelocityY += gravity * dt;
        isOnFloor = false;
    }
    else if (y > 444) {
        y = 444;
        VelocityY = 0;
    }
    else if (y == 444) {
        isOnFloor = true;
    }
    x += VelocityX;
    y += VelocityY;
}

int main() {
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "jump test");
    RectangleShape rect(Vector2f(20, 20));
    const int moveSpeed = 500;
    float jumpForce = 1;
    bool isKeyPressed = false;
    
    Clock deltaTime;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        dt = deltaTime.restart().asSeconds();
        Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            isKeyPressed = false;
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Space) {
                isKeyPressed = true;
            }
        }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) {
            VelocityX = moveSpeed * dt;
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) {
            VelocityX = -moveSpeed * dt;
        }
        else {
            VelocityX = 0;
        }


        if (isKeyPressed && isOnFloor){
            VelocityY = 0;
            VelocityY = -jumpForce;
            isKeyPressed = false;
            isOnFloor = false;
        }
        
        movement();
        rect.setPosition(x, y);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(rect);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `jumpForce` is 10 whereas `gravity * dt` will be 2 * (some really small value). The `jumpForce` value dominates, and `y` keeps on decreasing when space is pressed.

Comment: Ah okay, I have one more problem, the jumping height is a bit inconsistent, the characters jump height will increase or decrease. That is the only problem I have left, I edited the post to contain the new code

Comment: Doing float equality comparisons (y == 444) is rarely a good idea unless you're comparing against 0 or some other special numbers. Your `isOnFloor` is probably never going to be set to true. I would switch to using collision tests or using inequality tests with some tolerance.

Comment: I got a couple of questions, why are float equality comparisons a bad idea? And wouldn't ``isOnFloor`` at one point be true because the jump function works?

Comment: i didn't notice you set the height to 444 when it's below ground . I would suggest also setting isOnFloor to true here so you don't get one frame glitches. disregard my float equality comment, it's only true for when your comparing to decimal numbers.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks! Is there anything that can help solve my problem with the inconsistent jumps?